# Unit test controller, angularJS and jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, unit-testing

Hi I've been trying to unit test basic functions in my controller however I can't seem to connect when setting up the unit test.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Here is my controller:

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('studentController', function($scope,$route,$routeParams,$http,$location){


//Get all students
    $scope.getStudents = function(){
        $http.get('/api/student/').then(function(response){
            $scope.students = response.data;
        });
    };
```

and my test:

```
describe("studentController", function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var $controller;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }))

    describe("studentController", function(){
        it("should get student data", function (){
            var $scope = {};
            $scope.getStudents();
            expect($scope.students.length).toBe(15)
        })
    })

    });
```

I have included both these files in the jasmine html file along with the angular-mocks.js

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting `$route`, but you are not loading the ngRoute module. Load the file angular-route.js and state the dependency:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create controller in before each by using following and as you are calling getStudents that shuold be mocked by using HttpBackend service in unit test.

**Controller**

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('studentController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $http, $location) {
      //Get all students
      $scope.getStudents = function() {
        $http.get('/api/student/').then(function(response) {
          $scope.students = response.data;
        });
      };
    });
```

**Test file**

```
    describe("studentController", function() {
      beforeEach(module('myApp'));

      var $controller, scope, route;
      beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, $route, $routeParams, $http, $location) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('studentController', {
          '$scope': scope,
          '$route': $route,
          '$routeParams': $routeParams,
          '$http': $http,
          '$location': $location

        });

      }))

      describe("studentController", function() {
        it("should get student data", function() {
          // for this you have to use httpBackend
          // you have to mock the response of api
          $scope.getStudents();
          // then you are able to verify the result in student
          expect($scope.students.length).toBe(15)
        })
      })

    });
```

For more information you can refer [unit testing](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/) and [Httpbackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)